# Is there an only CSS way to synchronize the order of elements in 2 separate divs?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

In a directory site

D, E, F are post type entries (Wordpress) fetched in the B grid, and they are odered by their like counts, so their order is subject to change.

G, H, I are ads in column C, and they ideally should be horizontally "anchored" to the post entries, to achieve very related ads.

Meaning that if the order of the post entries in the grid changes to FDE top to bottom, then the order of the ads in their column should change accordingly to IGH, top to bottom.

Is there any pure CSS way to achieve this, or what would be the Javascript fix?

I was also told to keep the ads and the post entries in the same column, but that reduces styling possibilities (and overall possibilities), so I would prefer to keep them in 2 separate columns.

I do have the possibility to add custom selectors to both the individual ads and post entries, on demand.

Thanks!

Update:
additional detail - the number of the elements in both columns is increasing with new elements added.

Comment: Are you going to receive rating using PHP? Does the page already will be loaded with rating? How does the ration looks like? A digit? Floating dot? Show example of the rating please.

Comment: This is work for PHP only. Do you get both lists from PHP?

Comment: The rating is a digit accompanied by a heart icon, representing the number of likes. Yes the page will load with the rating loaded. The posts grid is by a WordPress plugin (mostly php) and the ads grid is also a WordPress plugin (php + javascript, but mostly javascript). I am not sure how exactly the like system works, I am most experienced in frontend stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly in one column you have a list of recent posts/blog articles updates when a new article is written. You want the adds on the right to always be directly across from their related article. This can not be accomplished with pure CSS as CSS can't make those calls.

If you have access to the HTML you could but D & G in their own div. E & H in their own div. Instead of having them share a column with the other items. But you would have to make sure that when you add a new article that things update correctly. That may call for some Jquery.

Comment: Thanks. I have no access to the HTML, and the order update I want it to be automatic once I assigned the designated selector to the elements, without HTML editing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are receiving those ratings using PHP. Although I think, this kind of sorting better to do using PHP on beck-end. But if you are looking for more like CSS solution - please take a look:

This part you need to get from your PHP in your template file. This is primitive construction, can write you more when will see your code. Here we are using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```
<style>
  :root {
    <?php $x = 1;
    foreach($latest_posts as $post) { ?>
    --x<?php echo $x; ?>: <?php echo $post['like_count']; ?>;
    <?php $x += 1; } ?> 
  }
</style>
```

And a code for sorting in separate blocks using CSS only.

```css
:root {
  --x1: 3;
  --x2: 2;
  --x3: 55;
}

.b, .c {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* this will helps us to order elements bakcwords, so the one with the highest number will be on the top */
  flex-direction: column-reverse; 
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.d, .g {
  order: var(--x1);
  background: yellow;
}

.e, .h {
  order: var(--x2);
  background: cyan;
}

.f, .i {
  order: var(--x3);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="d">d</div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
    <div class="f">f</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="g">g</div>
    <div class="h">h</div>
    <div class="i">i</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATED**

Fore any number of posts posts.

```
<style>
.flex-block {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* this will helps us to order elements bakcwords, so the one with the highest number will be on the top */
  flex-direction: column-reverse; 
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

<?php $x = 1;
foreach($latest_posts as $post) { ?>
.flex-block > div:nth-child(<?php echo $x; ?>) {order: <?php echo $post['like_count']; ?>;}
<?php $x += 1; } ?> 

</style>

<div class="flex-block left-one">
  <div>left 1</div>
  <div>left 2</div>
  <div>left 3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-block right-one">
  <div>right 1</div>
  <div>right 2</div>
  <div>right 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this work if the number of elements in both columns increases over time? More post entries will be submitted so their number will increase over time.

Comment: Updated the answer. Look please.

Comment: Thanks. Can the like_count be a meta key? I have a meta key: "like_count".

Comment: those `foreach` is just an example. you should take one from your news `foreach`, and add the style/php code in your news module. These are just an examples. If it will be to hard you can sent a link live site and I will write the exact code using JS.

Comment: Ok, i'll be posting more details. Thanks. In order for this to work, do I have to assign a common selector to each new post+ad pair? I trought I should assign a new, common selector to each new pair, like this: for D&G: selector1, for E&H: selector2, etc... otherwise in your current example how does the relation is established without a common selector?

Comment: I wouldn't like to reveal the actual project url. If you could please explain how the relation works without a common selector... I can see that you have not assigned selectors at all to the individual post entry/ad divs.

Comment: `.flex-block > div:nth-child(<?php echo $x; ?>)` - this one is a simple CSS child order selector. After PHP executed - it will be like `.flex-block > div:nth-child(1)`  and +1 for every circle. This means than we selects `div` (1) from  `.flex-block`, and put there `order: 345` for example. Now only thing we need is to make sure both our modules covered in `.flex-block`. Again, these are only examples for you to thing about and implement by yourself. There is nothing more I can do without real code.

Comment: everything in from tag `<style>`, including PHP - implement only in posts. same cover class `flex-block` should be implemented for both posts+ad

Comment: as long ad both POSTS and AD will have same class `.flex-block ` - we could access both using CSS with ` .flex-block > div:nth-child(1)` for the first child and so on. If you are too confused with all of this - please add html/php code of both of your modules in the code of your question.

Comment: I have sent you the URL to your mail on your profile: mail@focus.style. Thanks!